# Variable not being set in function

Tags: python

I am trying to set a variable in a function to false. I have it so the parameters contain the variable I wish to set to false but it always returns as True.

```
test1 = "item1"
item1 = True
britems = [test1]
inventory = []

def itemtake(item,iflag,roomit):
  if iflag == True:
    print("You take the", item)
    inventory.append(item)
    roomit.remove(item)
    iflag = False
    print(item,"=",iflag)
  else:
    print("Can't take that")

gameIn = input("Take?\n")

if gameIn == "take item1":
  itemtake(test1,item1,britems)
  print(test1,"=",item1)
```

in the function it prints that item1 = False, but outside of it it prints that it is True.

I've tried setting iflag to global but that gave an error, setting a variable to iflag and setting said variable to global, didn't work.

Comment: @wjandrea would global still work if you also pass in a iflag variable? Wouldn't python continue to overwrite the local version rather than changing the global?

Comment: @Portal Great question. I just tried it and it raises `SyntaxError: name 'g' is parameter and global`. (Python 3.8 and 3.10)

Comment: You can't overwrite the value of an argument to a function, _ever_. If it's a _mutable type_, you can _modify_ its value (e.g. appending to a list inside the function will persist outside the function), but you're trying to do it with a boolean value, which is immutable. The `global` keyword denotes that a _name_ is to be used from the global context.

Comment: `global` would work, assuming you used the global name (`global item1`); and `return False` would work, assuming you caught the return value (`item1 = itemtake(...)`). Please make a [mre] and include everything you've tried. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. *[Reposted to fix details]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Return your boolean value from your function, and set it outside:

```
def itemtake(item,iflag,roomit):
    ...
    return iflag


# Later, when you call the function:
item1 = itemtake(test1, item1, britems) 
# Now item1 is set to what you returned from the function
```

---

The `global` keyword denotes that a *name* is to be used from the global context. It has nothing to do with the actual value of the variable. Setting a name in a local context (such as inside a function) will only modify it in the current scope, unless that *name* has been denoted as a `global`.

You shouldn't <sup>can't?</sup> *set* or *overwrite* the value of an argument to a function and have it reflected outside (even with `global`, since the name of that value inside the function isn't necessarily the same as the name outside). Consider the following, which throws a SyntaxError:

```
def foo(bar):
    global bar        # SyntaxError: name 'bar' is parameter and global
    bar = not bar
```

If it's a *mutable type*, you can *modify* its value (e.g. appending to a list inside the function will persist outside the function). Consider the following snippet:

```
def foo(bar):
    bar.append("123")

lst = ["abc"]
foo(lst)

print(lst) # ["abc", "123"]
```

Unfortunately, you're trying to do this with a boolean value, which is immutable. In this case, you should *return* that value from your function, and *set* it where you called the function. Consider the following:

```
def foo(bar):
    bar = not bar # Sets the value in the local scope
    return bar    # Returns the modified value

boo = True

foo(boo)
print(boo)  # still True, because you never modified the value in the global scope

boo = foo(boo) 
print(boo)  # False, because you set the value of boo in this scope
```